# How do I non-permanently connect stranded wire to small screw?

Tags: wiring, wire, screw-terminal

This seems rather trivial, but I can't seem to find much information on this after a bit of searching online. I'm working on a project right now that requires me attach a [passive electrode](https://fri-fl-shop.com/product/tde-200/) to a wire, in order to carry a signal from that electrode. The sensor is mounted via a small screw that runs through its center (my guess is on the order of 1/16 of an inch diameter across the threading, but I can't recall exactly off the top of my head).

I started out simply by wrapping the wiring around the screw, and securing it with a nut. Except this process is incredibly unwieldy because the screw is so thin, and the way the sensor is mounted doesn't give me a lot of room to get my fingers in to wrap the wiring and screw the nut on. Though it's proved to be more than just inconvenient, because I have to install several dozens of these sensors and also replace them regularly.

Is there some sort of tool out there that makes this easier that I'm not aware of? Or some sort of small, electrically conductive eyelet I can attach to the screw and then attach to my wires? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm confused.  The electrodes you linked are intended to snap onto TDE-207 lead wires.  If you are using these on humans, you cannot just ignore this and use something you've jury rigged.  Anything that electrically interfaces with the human body is tightly and heavily regulated and certified.  Use the electrodes with the leads they are designed to snap onto, and make sure whatever they plug into has the right connector (safety plug).  It's that easy.

Comment: You can crimp a ring terminal on the wire.

Comment: @metacollin It's more of a pet project than a commercial or academic endeavor. I was trying a bit more of an adhoc approach to to cut personal cost rather than spending ~$8 for every three wires I purchase.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you are trying to work with?

Comment: Google on "ring terminal". They are cheap and widely available at any hardware store (in the US).

Comment: spade lugs come in all sizes and kits for wire attachment to screws. THe spade allows removal with a loose screw, and the ring requires the screw to be removed to insert.  THey have a color coded plastic sleeve. WHen done correctly it withstands a 2kg pull test without failure. or a a 5lb pull test)  two other types for crimp tools or solder tools are needed https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20

Comment: or look at the kit https://www.amazon.com/SOLOOP-Assorted-Terminal-Insulated-Connectors/dp/B01335ZEFE/ref=sr_1_8?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1497233502&sr=1-8&keywords=terminal+connectors  and see which dimensions work best for you, there are many varieties

Comment: For fine gauge wire, personally I would get spades with insulation crimps for strain relief https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/61238-1/A111364CT-ND/4142750

Comment: i use conductive glue on neodymium magnets and wire to make my own quick-connects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seek and ye shall find

ring or spade, insulated or not, crimp normally or solder, different diameters and AWG ranges
[image]